# I changed the values of GridLayout's RowDefinition and ColumnDefinition, but there is no change in the Grid

Tags: wpf, layout, grid

```
<Grid x:Name="xResult" Background="Fuchsia">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="xResultCol" Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition x:Name="xResultRow" Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="MainItem"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Background="red" />

        <Grid Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Background="Black" />

        <Grid Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Background="SkyBlue" />

        <Grid Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Background="DarkKhaki" />

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This is the Grid layout structure.
Under certain conditions, a 4-split screen should become 1 screen, and conversely, 1 screen should be divided into 4 split screens.

So in my case, I tried to make the Grid of the MainItem of 0,0 the main screen by setting the values of xResultCol and xResultRow to 0, but the Grid did not change.

```
    private void xMainGrid_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // 마우스 더블클릭 시 
        if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            if (xResult.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden)
                return;
    
            if (this.IsQuadView)
                return;
    
            // 1분할 화면에서는 Row=0, Col=0의 Grid를 확장하여 보여준다. 
            this.xResultCol = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Pixel) };
            this.xResultRow = new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Pixel) };
            this.xResult.UpdateLayout();
            this.xResult.InvalidateArrange();
    
    
        }
    }
private void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // 마우스 더블클릭 시 
    if ( e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        if (xResult.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden)
            return;

        if (this.IsQuadView)
            return;

        // 4분할 화면에서는 Row=0, Col=0의 Grid를 확장하여 보여준다. 
         this.xResultCol = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) };
        this.xResultRow = new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) };
        this.xResult.UpdateLayout();
        this.xResult.InvalidateArrange();


        // xResult내의 모든 그리드의 자식 Element를 제거한다.
        //ClearChildOfGridAndAddChild();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning new values to the `xResultCol` and `xResultRow` fields has no effect, because it does not change the actual `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinitions`.

You would simply change the `Width` and `Height` of the existing `ColumnDefinition` and `RowDefinition`:

```
private void OnMouseRightDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        xResultCol.Width = new GridLength(0);
        xResultRow.Height = new GridLength(0);
    }
}

private void OnMouseLeftDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        xResultCol.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        xResultRow.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }
}
```